# How to turn off OSR compilation

Tags: java, java-8, jvm-hotspot

I want to turn off OSR compilation and see the result of standard JIT compilation done by C1. I have restricted compilation to C1 using `-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1`, however I couldn't find anything on how to turn off OSR compilation. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 -XX:-UseOnStackReplacement
```

there is a command line argument for that.

Comment: Okay I think it did work, but should't it fall back to standard JIT compilation? It doesn't print any compilation at all now. My program is calls a function which has a loop that runs 100000 times. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tehreem I don't know - may be post a new question?